# converting notification area icon to Program icon in Win7 (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, windows-7

is there an easy way to convert my single instance app's notification(Systray) icon to a new Program icon (taskbar button) for Win7 with Delphi. (Source please)
Is it reasonable to keep the existing systray behaviour for old XP/Vista or should these also start using new model somehow?

Its recommended by MS:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx

Answer (score 5):

[Here you can find](http://www.gumpi.com/Blog/2009/01/20/Alpha1OfWindows7ControlsForDelphi.aspx) a alfa version of components to work with the new features of Windows 7.

- Jump Lists - right click your
  application entry on the taskbar to
  see those
- Overlay Icon - show the state of your
  application right in the taskbar
  (notification icons are hidden by Windows 7 by default, finally)
- Progress indicator in the taskbar
  button
- Taskbar Thumbnails - you application
  can be controlled directly from the
  taskbar preview window.

Download it and check if it is useful for you.

[Here there are some images](http://www.gumpi.com/Blog/CategoryView,category,Windows%2B7.aspx) of the demo program (compiled EXE is included).
The source also is included.